# make a custom view from xml

Tags: java, android, xml, view

I want to do a custom view coming from an XML.

Here's my XML :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/movieTitle"
        android:text="@string/movietitle"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <com.galite.headliner.views.LoaderImageView
        android:id="@+id/moviePoster" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/movieTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/poster"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movieDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:layout_below="@id/moviePoster"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And i want to inflate to a custom view because i need to use methods like onClick and everything.

Here's my constructor :

```
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
    initializeView();
}

public void initializeView(){
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie, null);
}
```

How can i make MyView equal to v ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to attach the inflated view `v` to `MyView` like this:

```
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie, this, true);
```

If you want that exact layout then make `MyView` to extend `RelativeLayout` and modify the xml layout like this:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/movieTitle"
        android:text="@string/movietitle"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <com.galite.headliner.views.LoaderImageView
        android:id="@+id/moviePoster" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/movieTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/poster"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movieDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:layout_below="@id/moviePoster"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</merge>
```

Comment: The method inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int, MovieView, boolean)